ImportExcel - Set-ExcelRange using column
Does anyone know if you can use the Set-ExcelRange cmdlet while referencing columns using Excel's column notation (like "E:G")? The -Range parameter doesn't seem to work with $sheet.Cells["E:G"]. $sheet.column(i) only seems to accept an integer.
Set-ExcelRange Help

Set-ExcelRange -Range $sheet.Cells["E:G"]  -HorizontalAlignment Right

Expected all cells in columns E, F, and G to have right alignment. Didn't format for me.

Set-ExcelRange using a range like E:G works perfectly fine however for it to take effect, you need to close the excel package which seems to be the step you're missing.
Putting into code and assuming you have gotten $sheet via Open-ExcelPackage:
$pkg = Open-ExcelPackage .\myfile.xlsx
$sheet = $pkg.Workbook.Worksheets['MyWorksheet']
Set-ExcelRange -Range $sheet.Cells['E:G'] -HorizontalAlignment Right
# last step is to close it so the updates take effect
Close-ExcelPackage $pkg

If you inspect the code for this function, the only thing it does is updating cell range instances (in memory), it never calls ExcelPackage.Save().
